# Passing parameters to controller when using Ruby on Rails and link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, controller, link-to

I am trying to create a route like this using Ruby on rails:

```
 get '/products/:store/:destination/:category/'
```

Sorry if this is trivial, but I'd need to know how build a controller for this, and it would be helpful to know how to pass the listed parameters from the views to the controller using an helper method such as 'link_to'.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can create the url by passing appropriate attributes :

```
<%=link_to 'Something Awesome', "/products/#{store}/#{destination}/#{category}"%>
```

I'm not sure what your use case is and how you plan to pass those parameters in the url.
But, you might want to create a `form_tag` instead for it's a much cleaner solution.

```
<%form_tag your_awesome_action_path do |f|%>
  <%=text_field_tag :store%>
  <%=text_field_tag :destination%>
  <%=text_field_tag :category%>
  <%=submit_tag 'Submit'%>
<%end%>
```

where, your_awesome_url is path to the controller action that will process the form.
you'll need an action your_awesome_action in the products controller and a corresponding route in routes.rb :

`match 'your_awesome_action' => 'products#your_awesome_action'.`